# How to publish android 11 app with permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to play store?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have app to write image file to folder, but when i publish to play store, the app got rejected because sensitive permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
[Rejected App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx2Rb.png)

I already change the compilesdk 29, but then got rejected again because minimal sdk is 30.
Please teach me how to publish my app with permission to write file on android 11 to playstore.

Comment: I think a lot of developers face this same issue with Android 11. That permission would make Playstore reject your app. But after the documentation, I think I saw where they wrote, that, you have to specify your reason for using that permission before you can publish it.

Comment: We like to teach you the way to write your file to a folder for which you do not need that permission.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: maybe you can make a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- #### Why your app got rejected

On Android 11, to use **`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`** permission your app need to fill one of these usecases:

- File managers
- Backup and restore apps
- Anti-virus apps
- Document management apps
- On-device file search
- Disk and file encryption
- Device-to-device data migration

As you said, your app only need to write a image to the storage, so you don't need the full-control of the Android OS file-system, which is the purpose of the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

So, ***to fix that, you need to use a more privacy-friendly API*** like [Shared Storage API `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media). This API allows you to write to external storage but this has some constraints which makes this API more privacy-friendly.

- #### What should I use?

It depends, depends on what your app need to do. But, in a nutshell, we can say that:

- The app need to write and read files frequently and need to share across the OS (Show in gallery, Shared Downloads folder, or something else that will be visible to the user)

  - Use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` API which allows you to manage external storage as well, refer to [MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_API reference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).
- The app need to export some files to shared scope (Gallery, Downloads folder, anything that will be visible to the user) but not frequently

  - Use [Shared Media API `WRITE/READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) which allows you to read and write to shared folders but with some constraints.
- The app only needs to storage user preferences, like, to keep theme, user config or something related to app data.

  - You don't need permission, see [app-specific files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)

- #### Resources

1. [Android Data Storage Overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)
2. [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)
3. [`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files)